# How to convert string to image format programatically

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a very long string from a text file automatically split into shorter string (a sentence maybe) and save as an image file. The preliminary program I am trying struggles with ANSI fonts, but works okey with other ttf fonts.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys

for i=0:10 
l = i;
for word in l:
    os.system("convert -fill black -background white -bordercolor red -border 6 -font AponaLohit.ttf -pointsize 100 label:\"%s\" \"%s.png\""%(word, word))
```

This program seems okey for single string but splitting larger string  into image seems hard. Any solution?

Comment: Do you have syntax errors? `for i=0:10` - it is no python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your *convert* program takes a string and makes the image out of it, what I understood from your question is that your problem seems to be splitting the text so that each substring doesn't go over a certain maximum length.

For this purpose, you can define the `MAX_LENGTH` constant and then iterate over your text, building substrings word-by-word until the maximum length is reached.

In code:

```
MAX_LENGTH = 80 # characters
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read().splitlines()
words = [ w for w in line.split(' ') for line in text ]
cur_word_index = 0
while cur_word_index < len(words):
    substring = []
    while cur_word_index < len(words) and len(substring) + len(words[cur_word_index]) + 1 <= MAX_LENGTH:
        substring.append(" " + words[cur_word_index])
        cur_word_index += 1
    os.system("convert -fill black -background white -bordercolor red -border 6 -font AponaLohit.ttf -pointsize 100 label:\"%s\" \"%s.png\"" %(substring, substring))
```

Explaining the algorithm:

We first read all the text from the file and split it into single words. Note that I'm assuming the text is separated by normal space characters.
This is done in the lines:

```
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read().splitlines()
words = [ w for w in line.split(' ') for line in text ]
```

Then we need to actually build the substrings.
Each iteration of the outer `while` loop creates a new substring and an image out of it.
We build the substring appending to it a word only if the current length of the substring plus the length of the word to add, plus one (for the space character in between) does not go over the `MAX_LENGTH`.
This is exactly what the inner loop does:

```
substring = []
while cur_word_index < len(words) and len(substring) + len(words[cur_word_index]) + 1 <= MAX_LENGTH:
    substring.append(" " + words[cur_word_index])
    cur_word_index += 1
```

Note that we need to check that the `cur_word_index` doesn't go over the words' list length.

Finally, with the substring completed, we call your external program and generate the image:

```
 os.system("convert -fill black -background white -bordercolor red -border 6 -font AponaLohit.ttf -pointsize 100 label:\"%s\" \"%s.png\"" %(substring, substring))
```